# How can I get when the bot is kicked of a voice channel

Tags: discord.js, disconnect

I search on Internet how can I do to get when the bot is kicked of a voice channel with the "Disconnect" button to send a message like "Bot disconnected of the voice channel" but I don't know how to get this information in discord.js
I code a music bot with playlist but when i kick the bot of the vc and i do the !play command, it add the music to the queue and don't join the channel.
I want clear the music queue with "queue.delete(guild.id)" whan the bot is kicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Use Connection Disconnect Event, It Will Execute Code When Bot Get Disconnected From A Voice Channel

```js
<Connection>.on("disconnect", () => {
   console.log("Disconnected From Voice Channel!");
  //...
});
```

Ex:

```js
queue.connection.on("disconnect", () => {
   console.log("disconnected from voice channel");
   client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
});
```

Links:
[Voice Connection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection)
[Disconnect Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=e-disconnect)